# how can i solve this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf') in my redux application

Tags: reactjs, function, redux, null, undefined

I am working on a redux project.
below is my `appSlice`

```
export const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: "app",
  initialState: {
    channelId: null,
    channelName: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    setChannelInfo: (state, action) => {
      state.channelId = action.payload.channelId;
      state.channelName = action.payload.channelName;
    },
  },
});
```

and here is my `chat.jsx`

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);
  //needed when you want to listen to a statechange in the database and fetch

  useEffect(() => {
    const messageRef = collection(db, "channels", channelId, "messages");
    onSnapshot(messageRef, (snapshot) => {
      setMessage(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
  }, [channelId]);
```

when I try to run my browser it gives me this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')

**pointing to my chat.jsx where i have const messageRef = collection(...)**

so I am suspecting that on the initial render it is reading a null value and so breaking my code.

*what have I tried?*

when I changed the **const channelId** in the **appSlice** to have a value rather than null, it works.

I just don't want it to have an initial value that is why it was null so that when the user now clicks on the id, it populates it.

so my question is how can I handle this error without having to change the initial state of my `channelId`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have a loading to wait until the database call is done and you have a value. Therefore I would just move the database call into its own hook and return three things `data, isLoading, error`. Then in your chat.jsx you can access the data by calling the hook:

`const [yourData, isLoading, error] = useYourCustomHook()`

Since the loading is there, you can return your loading indicator once database call is running and then update your state in `useEffect` once the data arrives.